# ASP Net Core - How to make route inheritance on multiple level?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm working on an API, and I have the following problem

I have abstract ApiController, like this

```
public abstract class ApiController<TService> : ApiController
    where TService : BaseService
{
    #region Fields

    /// <summary>
    /// Data manager
    /// </summary>
    protected TService Service { get; } = ServiceCollectionHelper.GetElementFromDependencyInjection<TService>();

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    #endregion
}

[ApiController]
[Authorize]
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api", Name = "BaseApiRoute")]
public abstract class ApiController : ControllerBase
{
}
```

I have multiple controllers, which inherit `ApiController<TService>`, or `ApiController`.

Example Controllers :

```
[Route("[controller]")]
public class RegionsController : ApiController<RegionService>
{
    #region Fields

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the regions
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="includeDepartments">Include the region departments</param>
    /// <returns>Regions</returns>
    [HttpGet]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<DepartmentDTO>), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<RegionDTO>>> GetAsync(bool includeDepartments = false)
    {
        return this.Ok(await this.Service.GetAsync(includeDepartments));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Normally, the route for the method `RegionsController.GetAsync` should be `/api/regions` with `GET` method, but it is `/regions`

Why the inheritance doesn't work, and how to correct that to have the `/api` prefix for all routes ?

I have tried to replace `[Route("/api")]` with `[Area("/api')]` but it didn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define `[Route("[controller]")]` on `RegionsController`, it overrides the base route.

Instead, you could define route with token replacement on base controller like:

```
[ApiController]
[Authorize]
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/[controller]", Name = "BaseApiRoute_[controller]")]
public abstract class ApiController : ControllerBase
{
}
```

See [token replacement and route inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#token-replacement-in-route-templates-controller-action-area) for more information.

> Attribute routes can also be combined with inheritance. This is powerful combined with token replacement. Token replacement also applies to route names defined by attribute routes.